# Dependency Error with common.io Library

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, implementation

I have been looking for an answer now but I cannot find the reason to why my build.gradle with the commons-io dependecy does not work. I'm currently following this tutorial: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Todo-App-Tutorial and adding the line `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'` inside the dependencies section in my build.gradle module file gives me an error of:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
Open File
Show Details
```

I have also tried changing versions of the implementation from 2.1-2.6 but that does not work either. From other threads, there are also posts saying to use commons-io:commons-io:(version) but that still pops up the same error. I have also tried to add the `mavenCentral()` call to both build.gradle files inside the repository method but it still shows the same error.

Here are my build gradle files.

Build gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

repositories{

    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.testing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: What does your app gradle file look like?

Comment: please post your build.gradle file

Comment: Updated with gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer. Problem was that I had Offline Work enabled in Android Studios.

To disable this, I did the following:

> `File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->gradle->untick box that says offline work`